# Is $\text{Gal}(\bar K/K) \cong \text{Gal}(\bar K[[x]]/K[[x]])$ hold?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

**First Section:**

There are two basic ways to construct examples of Galois extensions.

> $(1)$ Take any field $E$, any subgroup of $\text{Aut}( E )$, and let $F$ be the fixed field.
>
> $(2)$ Take any field $F$, any separable polynomial in $F [ x ]$, and let $E$ be its splitting field.
>
> > **Comment:** So in other words, given a field $K$, we can construct a group $G$ with pre-selected elements $\sigma$ and extend the field $K$ in such a way so that the above $G$ becomes the corresponding Galois group of the extension.

Am I right ?

**Second section:**

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and let $\bar K$ be the algebraic closure of $K$. Consider the Galois group $G=\text{Gal}(\bar K/K)$. Then consider the power series domains $K[[x]]$ and $\bar K[[x]]$. We have here the automorphic group $\text{Aut} K[[x]]$.

Is $\bar K[[x]]$ a Galois extension of $K[[x]]$ ?

Is $\text{Gal}(\bar K/K) \cong \text{Gal}(\bar K[[x]]/K[[x]])$ hold?

Some concept is available [here](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma330/files/moh_galois_theory.pdf)

Please respond both questions of each section

Comment: The power series extension piece is not even an extension of fields...

Comment: Can you prove that for $L/K$ Galois field extension then $Aut(L[[x]]/K[[x]])=Aut(L/K)$. @TokenToucan In some contexts an extension of (integral domains?) $S/R$ is said Galois if $R=S^G$ for some finite subgroup $G\le Aut(S)$ and infinite Galois if $S=\bigcup_n S_n, S_n\subset S_{n+1}$ with $S_n/R$ Galois.

Comment: @TokenToucan, this type of extensions is used in the link give below my question. He considered it as power series domain instead of power series ring.

Comment: @reuns, Given an automorphism $\sigma \in \text{Aut}(L/K)$ fixing elements $K$ can be extended to an power series $f(x)=\sum a_n x^n$ by acting on the coefficients of $f(x)$ i.e., $\sigma(f(x))=\sum \sigma(a_n)x^n$ fixing the coefficients of from the field $K$. That is, $\sigma \in \text{Aut}(L[[x]]/K[[x]])$. So $\text{Aut}(L/K) \subset\text{Aut}(L[[x]]/K[[x]])$. The reverse inclusion follows similarly by acting $\sigma$ restricting to constant power series. Am I right ? I hope some elements of $\text{Aut}(L[[x]]/K[[x]])$  is a power series also.

Comment: There is a hole in your comment. For a finite Galois extension $L/K$ then $L=\sum_{j=1}^n b_j K$ gives that $ L[[x]]=\sum_{j=1}^n b_j K[[x]]$  so the action of $\sigma\in Aut(L[[x]]/K[[x]])$ is defined by the $\sigma(b_j)$, but you need to show that $\sigma(b_j)\in L$, which is because the other elements are not algebraic over $K$. The fact that $K[[x]]=L[[x]]^{Aut(L/K)}$ was already giving that $Aut(L[[x]]/K[[x]])=Aut(L/K)$.

Comment: @reuns, Is the comment in $\text{First section }$ above correct ? I think it is inverse Galois theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adressing the 2nd section: For every algebraic extension $L/K$ the coefficient-wise action yields an injective homomorphism $\mathrm{Aut}(L/K)\rightarrow\mathrm{Aut}(L[[x]]/K[[x]])$.

Now let $f=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k\in L[[x]]$ be some element with the property $\sigma(f)=f$ for all $\sigma\in \mathrm{Aut}(L[[x]]/K[[x]])$. Then for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $f=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_kx^k+x^{n+1}g$, hence

$
f=\sigma(f)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \sigma(a_k)x^k+x^{n+1}\sigma(g).
$

Assume now that $L/K$ is normal. Since the elements $a_k$ are algebraic over $K$ the elements $\sigma(a_k)$ must be algebraic over $K$ as well and thus $\sigma(a_k)\in L$ for $k\in\{0,\ldots ,n\}$. Since $x^{n+1}\sigma(g)$ is a power series starting with a term of degree $n+1$ or higher one concludes $\sigma(a_k)=a_k$ for $k\in\{0,\ldots ,n\}$ and arbitrary $n$. Among the $\sigma$ are those automorphisms that act coeficient-wise, therefore $a_k\in L^{\mathrm{Aut}(L/K)}$.

If $L/K$ is Galois one thus gets $L[[x]]^{\mathrm{Aut}(L[[x]]/K[[x]])}=K[[x]]$.

I just realized that a similar argument shows that every $\sigma\in\mathrm{Aut}(L[[x]]/K[[x]])$ acts coefficent-wise so that the answer to the second question is 'yes'.

Comment: I think this is a nice answer. But I have few questions. See in the following comments.

Comment: First Question: In the second line you assumed $\sigma(f)=f$ for all $\sigma \in Aut(L[[x]]/K[[x]])$. Does it mean all $\sigma$s fixes this particular $f$ ? Or Does it mean all  $\sigma$ is identity , which is absurd ?? Because $\sigma(f)=\sum \sigma(a_k)x^k = f$  not always ?

Comment: Second Question: What does give extra benefit by splitting the power series $f$ into a polynomial $+$ a power series starting from $(n+1)^{th}$ term?

Comment: Third question: You said "Since $x^{n+1}\sigma(g)$ is a power series starting with a term of degree $n+1$ or higher one concludes $\sigma(a_k)=a_k$ for $k\in\{0,\ldots ,n\}$ and arbitrary $n$". Why this hold ? Can you explain please? why can not be $\sigma(a_n)=a_{n+1}$ or $\sigma(a_n)=a_{n+2}$ ?

Comment: 1. In your original post you ask if $L[[x]]|K[[x]]$ is Galois. In my opinion this at least means that $K[[x]]$ is the ring of all elements in $L[[x]]$ fixed by all $\sigma$. This is what I show. 2. The idea is to compare coefficients of the power series involved, since these coefficients are unique. But a priori it is not clear that $\sigma(\sum\limits_k a_kx^k)=\sum\limits_k\sigma(a_kx^k)$; the splitting helps out here. 3. $\sigma(a_k)=a_k$ follows because among the $\sigma$ considered are those acting component-wise.

Comment: oh,  got the answer of first question.Thanks